# Delete row in TableView when I use UIActionSheet to confirm

Tags: ios, uitableview

I use UIActionSheet to confirm for deleting row in TableView. I have 3 rows  but when I swap to delete first row, the first row not delete but the third row is deleted. After I continue to  delete first row again but second row is deleted. I don't know why. Please help me to resolve this small problem.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

}

}





-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{


switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:

        [listOfName removeObjectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];
         //selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
        [self viewWillAppear:YES];

}


}
```

Comment: Show the method where you are deleting rows, commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Yes I used this methode.

Comment: Of course you did. Post here what you have inside those methods..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem

```
[listOfName removeObjectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];
```

The value of `selectedIndex` of your `UIActionSheet` is always 0 since that is not set to the index of table row to be deleted.

Set it's value to the `indexPath.row` before presenting the `UIActionSheet`.

```
self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Then in `clickedButtonAtIndex:` method within the `case` 0, make sure you reload the table view.

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove the element from the array and again reload the table view

Answer (score 0):

I found this delegate method, which i guess, you already have implemented.

```
tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:
```

From my point of view, you should store the toIndexPath as a property or attribute and when the user confirms, delete it, with the stored "toIndexPath". If the user cancels this action, set the property or attribute to nil (in ARC context or in NON-ARC context release the attribute and set it to nil aswell).

Answer (score 0):

remove element from your array .

```
[yourArray removeObject:indexpath.row];
```

reload your tableview.

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
       {
            selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
           UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles: nil];
          [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
       }
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
      switch (buttonIndex) {
          case 0:

              [listOfName removeObjectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];
              [tableView reloadData];
        }
}
```